# how to adjust character spacing of a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

How could I adjust the character spacing in a label control. There is no such a property in the property window.

```
<asp:Label ID="label01" runat="server" Text="EXPLORATIONS" Font-Bold="True"     
Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#999999"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply a `CssClass` to your `Label` control in which you can give letter spacing.

Something like this

```
<style type="text/css">
        .spacing
        {
            letter-spacing:12px;
        }
</style>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Your nice text line" 
      CssClass="spacing" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the CSS [`letter-spacing` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp):

```
<asp:Label ID="label01" runat="server" Text="EXPLORATIONS" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#999999" CssClass="YourStyle" />

<style>
.YourStyle
{
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [css](/questions/tagged/css), you can adjust the [letter spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/letter-spacing):

```
label#label01{
    letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```